# How to pass array of JSON object to REST API as input claim in custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am calling a REST API from custom policy. 
I am sending JSON data in the request body, and a sample JSON data is"

I am little bit confused how to send the below JSON (address and contacts) as input claim from my custom policy.

```
{
  "firstName": "sampleuser",
  "lastName": "qa",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "countryCode": "IN"
    }
  ],
  "contacts": {
    "email": {
      "address": "sampleuserqa@mailinator.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

B2C can only build a JSON from its own claim type primitives. Which are int, boolean, datetime, string, stringCollection.

For example, by outputting these claims in a REST API technical profile:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="firstName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="lastName" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="addresses" />
```

With these definitions:

```xml
  <ClaimType Id="firstName">
    <DisplayName>firstName</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
  </ClaimType>
  <ClaimType Id="lastName">
    <DisplayName>lastName</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
  </ClaimType>
  <ClaimType Id="addresses">
    <DisplayName>addresses</DisplayName>
    <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
  </ClaimType>
```

The resulting JSON payload to the API will be

```
{
  "firstName": "sampleuser",
  "lastName": "qa",
  "addresses": "X, Y, Z",
}
```

Since we do not model the json object themselves, we cannot build a JSON payload like:

```
  "addresses": [
    {
      "countryCode": "IN"
    }
  ],
  "contacts": {
    "email": {
      "address": "sampleuserqa@mailinator.com"
    }
  }
```

Depending on how you are obtaining this information from a user or backend system, this JSON claims transformation might be helpful in splitting the data into string/stringCollections to send the data to an API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/stringcollection-transformations